# IE Not Saving Cookie

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

I have a user who has their privacy setting on Medium in IE.  When they go to my site it, the cookie is not setting.  This has occurred on 2 machines with the same settings, while other machines with IE are working fine on a Medium setting.

```
     $('select').change(function(){
checkCookie();
if (jQuery.cookie('newcity') ) { 
    $.cookie( 'newcity', null, { path: '/', domain:'928shopper.com'});
}

$.cookie('newcity', this.value, {expires: 7, path: '/', domain:'928shopper.com'});

});
```

All the other browsers on these machines are fine with the function.  When I test is cookies are enabled, it comes back true.  Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out what it was!  Users with IE that were not writing the cookie had Protected Mode enabled.

Internet Options/Security/Protected Mode(uncheck to write the cookie)